# Notification display for when a data is about to expire

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

using C# and sqlite and winforms

I just wanted to know is it possible to have a reminder notification. I want the user to input a certificate, when they did partook in getting the cert and when the cert expires. The reminder is somewhat similar to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQowDMoTdNg, but instead of needing the user to click on the button like in the video, is there a way for the notification to pop up when both

1. The certificate is about to expire and
2. when the user switches on his pc?

Answer (score 0):

tow achieve your requirement you need to do following things

1. you need to create a functionality to read certificate and find expire time

https://prashantbiztalkblogs.wordpress.com/tag/get-certificate-about-to-expire-programatically-using-c/

2. You need to create window service or background service in winform application to raise notification base on result produce by your above function

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/changhuixu/2a5b91da93c603fcd6fcc5f99c53c48d/raw/201fd3284e0732b481f174c5eb69d6bf36033292/Worker.cs

Comment: Oh the certificate isn't that huge. What I meant was just the name of the certificate so its just a string. Sorry for misleading